# $f_n(t) = \sum_{k=1}^{n}k e^{-\frac{(k-t)^2}{C}}$ is this function sequence uniformly bounded?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis

Let $C>0$ be a absolute constant ,$f_n(t) = \sum_{k=1}^{n}k e^{-\frac{(k-t)^2}{C}}$ is this function sequence uniformly bounded?

Comment: I take it you want $C>0$?

Comment: @saulspatz yes ...

Comment: Please edit the question to make this clarification.  You will also get a lot more help if you indicate what you have done on the problem yourself.  Without more context, you are liable to get a lot of down votes and votes to close.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it isn't.  $$f_n(n)= \sum_{k=1}^{n}k e^{-\frac{(k-n)^2}{C}}=\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}k e^{-\frac{(k-n)^2}{C}}+ne^0>n$$